# egrep to list devices in /dev directory

Tags: grep, ubuntu-12.04, tty

I am using following command in my Python code to list devices available in `/dev` directory:

```
 devices = ["/dev/" + x for x in os.popen("ls /dev/ | egrep -i 'ttyUSB|ttyS'").read().strip().split('\n')]
```

How can I modify it to find only `ttyS0` and `ttyS1`? Currently it returns all ttyS s :

```
ttyS0,ttyS1, ttyS11, ttyS12, ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the pattern to the following:

```
 devices = ["/dev/" + x for x in os.popen("ls /dev/ | egrep -i 'ttyUSB|ttyS[01]$'").read().strip().split('\n')]
```

Comment: this returns: ['/dev/ttyS0', '/dev/ttyS1', '/dev/ttyS10', '/dev/ttyS11', '/dev/ttyS12', '/dev/ttyS13', '/dev/ttyS14', '/dev/ttyS15', '/dev/ttyS16', '/dev/ttyS17', '/dev/ttyS18', '/dev/ttyS19']

Comment: Thanks,you are right,I didn't add that for the first test. Works great